# SQL Server - 2008 Column Data Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below Case Statment and I'm inserting this into a new table. The column under the new table is Varchar but I need it as an INT. I have changed the data type using the Alter statment but I frequenctly delete and create the same table. Is there a way to have the new table create the data type of INT instead of varchar for the below syntax?

```
CASE WHEN F.END_DATE IS NOT NULL OR F.REASON IS NOT NULL  THEN '0' ELSE '1' END Enrolled'
```

Comment: if you want an `INT` instead of `VARCHAR` then **why** are you using `THEN '0' ELSE '1' END` instead of `THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the single quotes around 0 and 1:

```
CASE WHEN F.END_DATE IS NOT NULL OR F.REASON IS NOT NULL  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Enrolled'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
CASE WHEN coalesce(F.END_DATE,F.REASON ,0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Enrolled
```